# A bounded linear map that cannot be both surjective and injective

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two Banach spaces. Assume that $f$ is linear bounded mapping from $X$ to $Y$ such that for all $n$, there exists $a_n$ with $||a_n||=1$ and $||f(a_n)||=\frac{1}{n}.$ Prove that $f: X \rightarrow Y$ cannot be both surjective and injective.

---

I think that when I first assume that $f$ is onto, I will get a contradiction to Open Mapping Theorem. Could you provide me with an initial step to begin? Even though I figured out the scheme. I couldn't find where to begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $f$ is bijective then $f^{-1}$ is continuous by Open Mapping Theorem. So $\|f^{-1}y|| \leq C \|y\|$ for all $y \in Y$ where $C$ is the norm of $f^{-1}$. Taking $y=fx$ we get $\|x\|\leq C\|f(x)\|$ for all $x \in X$. What happens to this when  you take $x=a_n$ and let $n \to \infty$?

Comment: We get a contradiction as we get $1 < 0$. Thank you a lot!.